# How to create a non-overlapping buffer with a 50km radius having the RasterLayer file and centroids

Tags: r, raster-calculator

I have a RasterLayer file and the relative shapefile showing the centroids of every cell. My goal is to compute a buffer with a 50 km radius starting from the centroids and then calculate the average altitude within these buffers. The problem is that ArcGIS does not perform this computation since buffers overlap. I want to solve this problem in R. How can I compute non-overlapping buffers with these files?

Comment: I have already tried the gBuffer command but R tells me :"unable to find an inherited method for function ‘is.projected’ for signature ‘"RasterLayer"

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: You run the buffer on the centroids, and then use an extraction method on the buffers over the raster layer. If you show us the code you have to read the data in then we might get on with this for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was thinking about this procedure, but the problems arise when I try to use "extract": R tells me "unable to find an inherited method for function ‘extract’ for signature ‘"RasterLayer", "sfc_POINT". So I don't know how to fix this problem. As follows there are the codes I have used

Comment: cen <- st_read("grid5050_centroids.shp");                                                                        
ras<-raster("Euro_DEM_WGS.tif");                                                                              
#Extract and plot geometry 
geo<-st_geometry(cen) ;                                                                                                #Create a buffer of 50km
buffers <- st_buffer(cen, dist = 50000, dissolve=TRUE) ;                                                                                     
mean <- extract(b, geo, fun=mean)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using `terra` explained in the comments in detail:

```r
library(terra)
#> terra 1.6.3

# Read raster
dgm <- terra::rast("dgm200_utm32s.asc")

# You can probably skip this if your crs is defined properly
terra::crs(dgm) <- "epsg:25832"

# Inspect object
dgm
#> class       : SpatRaster 
#> dimensions  : 4331, 3211, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#> resolution  : 200, 200  (x, y)
#> extent      : 279900, 922100, 5235700, 6101900  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. : ETRS89 / UTM zone 32N (EPSG:25832) 
#> source      : dgm200_utm32s.asc 
#> name        : dgm200_utm32s

# Create random points using the extent of your raster, these would be your centroids.
# If you have to load existing vector data using terra, make use of `terra::vect()`.
p <- terra::spatSample(dgm, 10, "random", na.rm = TRUE, as.points = TRUE)

# Create a buffer of 50 km around your points
b <- terra::buffer(p, width = 50000)

# Inspect visually if everything seems fine so far
terra::plot(dgm)
terra::plot(p, add = TRUE)
terra::plot(b, add = TRUE)
```

[image]

```r
# Extract values from raster using buffer polygons, aggregate function: mean
result <- terra::extract(dgm, b, fun = mean, cells = TRUE, na.rm = TRUE)

# Inspect result
head(result)
#>   ID dgm200_utm32s
#> 1  1     402.35157
#> 2  2     402.41608
#> 3  3     431.44838
#> 4  4     475.62804
#> 5  5      38.25646
#> 6  6      26.83238
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much! I have run it and it gives me the average altitude as a result. I just have another question: I have the coordinates of the centroid (lat/lon) as a shapefile, is it correct to upload the relative file with the following code?                                              cen <- st_read("grid5050_centroids.shp")
geo<-st_geometry(cen)
c<-terra::vect(cen)
The code system.file(...., packages=terra) does not work for me. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You're welcome! Your example should work - you're creating a simple feature collection from your shapefile (sf) which you use to derive a geometry set (sf) which in turn is used to create a SpatVector object (terra) - but why don't you use `terra::vect("grid5050_centroids.shp")` directly?

Comment: You are right! Done, it works. Thank you again!